# unable to start isc-dhcp-server

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, dhcp

I am unable to start isc-dhcp-server.
When I run the command to start the dhcp-server. I get the bellow error

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/dhcp $ sudo service isc-dhcp-server start
Job for isc-dhcp-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service
● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-03-25 12:23:56 EDT;
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1493 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited

Mar 25 12:23:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Control
Mar 25 12:23:56 raspberrypi dhcpd[1504]: If you think you have received 
Mar 25 12:23:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed 
Mar 25 12:23:56 raspberrypi dhcpd[1504]: than a configuration issue plea
Mar 25 12:23:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server
Mar 25 12:23:56 raspberrypi dhcpd[1504]: bugs on either our web page at 
Mar 25 12:23:56 raspberrypi dhcpd[1504]: before submitting a bug.  These
Mar 25 12:23:56 raspberrypi dhcpd[1504]: process and the information we 
Mar 25 12:23:56 raspberrypi dhcpd[1504]: 
Mar 25 12:23:56 raspberrypi dhcpd[1504]: exiting.
```

Here is my dhcpd.conf file

```
# dhcpd.conf
#
# Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd
#

# option definitions common to all supported networks...
option domain-name "example.org";
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

# The ddns-updates-style parameter controls whether or not the server will
# attempt to do a DNS update when a lease is confirmed. We default to the
# behavior of the version 2 packages ('none', since DHCP v2 didn't
# have support for DDNS.)
ddns-update-style none;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
#authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
#log-facility local7;

# No service will be given on this subnet, but declaring it helps the 
# DHCP server to understand the network topology.

#subnet 10.152.187.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#}

# This is a very basic subnet declaration.

#subnet 10.254.239.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range 10.254.239.10 10.254.239.20;
#  option routers rtr-239-0-1.example.org, rtr-239-0-2.example.org;
#}

# This declaration allows BOOTP clients to get dynamic addresses,
# which we don't really recommend.

#subnet 10.254.239.32 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range dynamic-bootp 10.254.239.40 10.254.239.60;
#  option broadcast-address 10.254.239.31;
#  option routers rtr-239-32-1.example.org;
#}

# A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet.
#subnet 10.5.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range 10.5.5.26 10.5.5.30;
#  option domain-name-servers ns1.internal.example.org;
#  option domain-name "internal.example.org";
#  option routers 10.5.5.1;
#  option broadcast-address 10.5.5.31;
#  default-lease-time 600;
#  max-lease-time 7200;
#}

# Hosts which require special configuration options can be listed in
# host statements.   If no address is specified, the address will be
# allocated dynamically (if possible), but the host-specific information
# will still come from the host declaration.

#host passacaglia {
#  hardware ethernet 0:0:c0:5d:bd:95;
#  filename "vmunix.passacaglia";
#  server-name "toccata.example.com";
#}

# Fixed IP addresses can also be specified for hosts.   These addresses
# should not also be listed as being available for dynamic assignment.
# Hosts for which fixed IP addresses have been specified can boot using
# BOOTP or DHCP.   Hosts for which no fixed address is specified can only
# be booted with DHCP, unless there is an address range on the subnet
# to which a BOOTP client is connected which has the dynamic-bootp flag
# set.
#host fantasia {
#  hardware ethernet 08:00:07:26:c0:a5;
#  fixed-address fantasia.example.com;
#}

# You can declare a class of clients and then do address allocation
# based on that.   The example below shows a case where all clients
# in a certain class get addresses on the 10.17.224/24 subnet, and all
# other clients get addresses on the 10.0.29/24 subnet.

#class "foo" {
#  match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 4) = "SUNW";
#}

#shared-network 224-29 {
#  subnet 10.17.224.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-224.example.org;
#  }
#  subnet 10.0.29.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-29.example.org;
#  }
#  pool {
#    allow members of "foo";
#    range 10.17.224.10 10.17.224.250;
#  }
#  pool {
#    deny members of "foo";
#    range 10.0.29.10 10.0.29.230;
#  }
#}
authoritative;
subnet 192.68.50.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.50.10 192.168.50.250;
option domain-name "local"
option domain-name-servers 192.168.50.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
option routers 192.168.50.1;
option broadcast-address 192.168.50.255;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
interface eth0;
}
```

and interface file

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/network $ cat interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.50.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.50.0
broadcast 192.168.50.255

up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.net
```